# WPF - Border & TextBlock - Strange Behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border

I have this very simple XAML markup

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontSize="20"/>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.25"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontSize="19" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.25"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

... and no code in the code-behind file.

But the result is very strange..., the border in the first stackpanel becomes fluffy when the application runs, the border in the second stackpanel is sharp and nice.

The only difference is found in th two textblocks, the first textblock has a fontsize of 20, the second textblock has a fontsize of 19.

So what triggers the fluffyness of the first border...?

Comment: And if you set the FontSize on the first textbox to 19?

Comment: Then the first Border is sharp and fine.

Comment: What if you use size 18?  What about a different font?  I have seen strange font rendering when using point sizes that fall in between "expected" point sizes for the font.  Is this on a standard resolution display?

Comment: really strange effect it works fine in case of an odd font size.

Comment: I changed the fontsize to 21, and the problem goes away.

I haven't done anything special like changing the font or anything, so yes, I think it's the combination of the font and the font-size. It runs on my standard Microsoft Surface Pro 3.

I will go for another fontsize, laugh about it and close this thread.

Great thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try UseLayoutRounding="True" in your grid.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UseLayoutRounding);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2)&rd=true

```
    <Grid Margin="20" UseLayoutRounding="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontSize="20"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.25"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontSize="19" />
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.25"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Indeed if I set `UseLayoutRounding="True"` in the grid, the two borders are hidden. On the other side, if I set `UseLayoutRounding="True"` in the first TextBlock (the one whose font size is 20) the "fluffy effect" disappears (VS 2013, .NET 4.0)